# selected items from listview not working

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

Basing off http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html, here is my getView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Model m = getItem(position);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    /* convertView will be null if convertView isn't from recycler
     */
    if(convertView == null) {
        Log.d("SELECT_ADAPTER", "convertView is null; Position=" + position + " and " +
              " model=" + m.getTitle());
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection_item, parent, false);

        // inflate individual views and cache them into viewholder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        viewHolder.cb.setChecked(m.isSelected());
        viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                allModels.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
            }
        });


        viewHolder.pictureIV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById((R.id.Picture));
        viewHolder.playBtnIV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById((R.id.ivPlayBtn));

        // associate view memory with these views
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        convertView.setTag(R.id.cb, viewHolder.cb);

    }
    else {
        Log.d("SELECT_ADAPTER", "Reusing convertView, position=" + position + "and " +
               " model=" + model.getTitle());
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.cb.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.cb.setChecked(allModels.get(position).isSelected());
    // associate play button with model so listener callback knows which video to launch
    viewHolder.playBtnIV.setTag(m);

    // set values in views
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(m.getImageUrl(), viewHolder.pictureIV);

    return convertView;
}
```

When I click on a button in Activity A I go through all the models and based on the flag set in the aforementioned listener, creates a list of "selected" model instances like so:

```
public void onClickResultsBtn(View v) throws Exception {   
    for (MyModel m: allModels) {
        if (m.isSelected()) 
            selectedModels.add(m);
    }
....
```

Then Activity B is started.  When I press back on Activity B to return to Activity A, I override Activity A's onResume to clear this selected models list so that if I edit my selection, the selected models list will be properly updated and not contain duplicates from the last button press:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(results != null && results.size() > 0) {
        results.clear();
        selectedModels.clear();
    }
}
```

If I press back on Activity B and edit my selections in Activity A the selectedModels list is not correct(I see extra values).

Comment: "editing my selections in between activities" What does this mean? How can you be "between activities"?

Comment: select item 1, 2, 15.  hit button.  hit back.  deselect item 15, deselect item 2, select item 3, select item 15 again.  hit button.  in the select screen(Activity A), the list of selections sometimes has duplicates like item 15, 15, 2 and 3.  Not an exact example.